# How change color title tab in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How i can change color title kivymd tab:

```
MDTabs:
    id: tabs
    text_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
    text_color_active: 1, 0, 0, 1
    color_indicator: 0.95, 0.95, 0.1, 1
```

everything this doesn't work, text color is remains defoult (white). Please advice me anything
I install this: `https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/082405ec4ccb9dd454521b266d5ef04d520c703b.zip`, but nothing not change. Please help, i don't understand what me do

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in the master branch of the KivyMD library - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/commit/082405ec4ccb9dd454521b266d5ef04d520c703b#diff-9dd6a8b5c5d51f6352fdddd8ac078096584d3db5f51d6d6f0819d1bc897881ec

Comment: It fixes that issue but brings breaks the on_focus method.; it switches to persistent after one time. Not sure if that was an issue or not 1 year ago. You'll have that with unreleased packages XD.